# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, ssl, flask, google-ads-api

Tried Option didn't work used in app.py

```
os.environ['PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY'] = '0'
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

using flask

```
data = report_downloader.DownloadReport(
report, output, skip_report_header=False, skip_column_header=False,
skip_report_summary=False, include_zero_impressions=True)
```

and trying to get ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT working fine on local system when used tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6 as docker base image and deployed giving below error

```
 File "/google-analytics/helper_service/service.py", line 328, in sync_google_ads_word_data
skip_report_summary=False, include_zero_impressions=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleads/common.py", line 405, in Wrapper
return utility_method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleads/adwords.py", line 1268, in DownloadReport
output, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleads/adwords.py", line 1540, in _DownloadReport
response = self._DownloadReportAsStream(post_body, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleads/adwords.py", line 1614, in _DownloadReportAsStream
response = self.url_opener.open(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
'_open', req)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)>
```

Comment: RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install ca-certificates -y && apt-get autoremove -y adding in docker image worked for me